# How can I animate the element when animation finished its sequence

Tags: css, html

I want to animate the `parent-round-div` when returning back to its original size. Is it possible to make animation after finishing its current animation?

This is my code:

```
.parent-round-div{
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation-name: sizeAnimate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s ;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: sizeAnimate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.child-round-div{
  margin:10%;
  position:relative;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  width:70px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sizeAnimate{
  from{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
  to{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}
@keyframes sizeAnimate{
  from{
    width:70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
  to{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}



<div class = "parent-round-div">
  <div class="child-round-div">
    A
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When would the initial effect take place? Is it on a hover, or click? Does it make a difference to when the second animation takes place? If not - you could just add an animation-delay http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Comment: When the page load the animation take place and after the animation another animation will be fired on the parent-round-div.

Comment: @AbzRockers The question is not very clear. When should the second animation happen and how should it be triggered? Should it be automatically triggered immediately after the first animation is completed? Should it be triggered after some delay? Should it be triggered after user interaction? When?

Comment: @Harry - sorry for not making it clear. It should be triggered after the current animation finished executing.

Comment: @AbzRockers: Do you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/812off90/)?

Comment: -Harry thank you very much, that is the answer I am looking for. That should be the answer for me, but how I can it a right answer if your answer is on the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a correct answer on my question rather than deleting the question, I copy and pasted the answer of Harry. (found on the jsfiddle link he commented)
This is his answer:

```css
.parent-round-div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  animation-name: sizeAnimate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.child-round-div {
  margin: 10%;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
@keyframes sizeAnimate {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
  45%, 55% {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-round-div">
  <div class="child-round-div">
    A
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!